# Mouse events for Unity3D isometric tile map

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, tile, isometric

I have been reading up on the new tile map system in Unity3D. I have managed to get to the point of setting up a grid -> tile-map and setting up a tile palette. However now i'm struggling with finding up-to-date tutorials for handling mouse events for this new tile map system.

I'm attempting to set a highlight when the mouse is over the tile and if the tile is clicked I want to be able to trigger scripts and other events. However the available tutorials online don't go into mouse events for the tile map system and very few talk about isometric tile maps.

Are there any good up to date tutorials for handling mouse events on an isometric tile map? Even a simple tutorial showing a hover effect on the tile and a "hello world from tile x.y" when tile is clicked, would be all i would really need to get going.

This is what I have so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 clickPosition = Vector3.one;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            clickPosition = hit.point;
        }
        Debug.Log(clickPosition);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This should get you started:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

   //You need references to to the Grid and the Tilemap
   Tilemap tm;
   Grid gd;

   void Start() {
       //This is probably not the best way to get references to
       //these objects but it works for this example
       gd = FindObjectOfType<Grid>();
       tm = FindObjectOfType<Tilemap>();
   }

   void Update() {

       if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
           Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
           Vector3Int posInt = gd.LocalToCell(pos);

           //Shows the cell reference for the grid
           Debug.Log(posInt);

           // Shows the name of the tile at the specified coordinates
           Debug.Log(tm.GetTile(posInt).name);
       }
   }
}
```

In short, get a reference to the grid and tilemap.  Find the local coordinates using ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).  Call the LocalToCell method of the grid object to get your local coordinates (Vector3) converted to cell coordinates (Vector3Int).  Pass the cell coordinates to the GetTile method of the Tilemap object to get the Tile (then use the methods associated with the Tile class to make whatever changes you want to make).

In this example, I just attached the above script to an empty GameObject in the world.  It would probably make sense to attach it to the Grid, instead.  The general logic remains the same nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

This is a slightly different version from the way HumanWrites does it. It doesn't require a reference to the grid, and the mousePos is declared as a Vector2, rather than a Vector3 - this will avoid problems when working in 2D.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class MouseManager : MonoBehaviour
{

private Tilemap tilemap;

void Start()
{
    tilemap = FindObjectOfType<Tilemap>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3Int gridPos = tilemap.WorldToCell(mousePos);

        if (tilemap.HasTile(gridPos))
            Debug.Log("Hello World from " + gridPos);
    }
}

}
```

The 'tilemap' that we're referencing is a gameObject in your scene. You may have renamed it to something else, but it would be a child of the 'Grid' object.
[image]

Comment: for the section .Find("Tilemap") is this looking for the name of the component or the tag?